# Xcode XCTest measure performance with async queues

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

A framework that I have written for my app downloads different chunks of data that get processed. Naturally, larger sets of data take more time to process. To better investigate how to improve, I thought about writing Tests to measure performance to see where/if it's worth looking into.

Generally, the `measure` block works, however, to avoid blocking the main thread, I process the data asynchronously. Because of that, I'm unable to measure "from start to finish" as the `measure` block disregards async blocks and finishes the Test before my async queue has finished processing all the data.

I have written a minimal example to demonstrate what I mean.

`DownloadHandler` is the class that receives the data in my framework. `Database` is a class in my app and models where the data ends up and gets processed. In my app, the AppDelegate connects these two, but for the sake of the Test, the Test class does that in this case.

This is the console output of what's happening:

```
File A
Sent A to Database

File B
Sent B to Database

File C
 Processed file A in Database 
 Processed file B in Database 
Sent C to Database
[End of Test]
```

But what I would need is to wait for the Test to have the queue to finish processing all the data before stopping. In other words, it's missing a final

```
 Processed file B in Database
```

Below you will find my example code to demonstrate. The actual implementation is much more complex with different handlers for different purposes but I simulate the "work done" with the `usleep`

DownloadHandler.swift

```
import Foundation

public protocol HandlerDelegate {
    func interpretData(s: Character)
}

class DownloadHandler {
    
    var delegate: HandlerDelegate!
    
    func receivedFiles(files: String) {
        
        for file in files {
            print("\nFile \(file)")
            usleep(100000)
            delegate.interpretData(s: file)
            print("Sent \(file) to database")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Database.swift

```
class Database {
    
    let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "databaseSerial")
    
    var entries = [Character]()
    
    func interpretData(s: Character) {
        serialQueue.async {
            usleep(100000)
            self.entries.append(s)
            print(" Processed file \(s) in database")
        }
    }
    
}
```

TestFrameworkTests.swift

```
import XCTest
@testable import TestFramework

class TestFrameworkTests: XCTestCase, HandlerDelegate {
    
    func interpretData(s: Character) {
        database.interpretData(s: s)
    }
    
    var handler = DownloadHandler()
    var database = Database()
    
    var testData = "ABC"

    func testPerformanceExample() throws {
        
        handler.delegate = self
        
        let options = XCTMeasureOptions()
        options.iterationCount = 0

        measure(options: options) {
            print("\n\nTEST ITERATION")
            handler.receivedFiles(files: testData)

        }
    }

}
```

I suppose there is some XCTest feature that I'm not aware of but I can't wrap my head around what to search for in order to find something I can adapt.

Comment: My first thought would be not to use tests for this. This isn't really the purpose of the test framework. Use the time profiler instrument, but are you looking for [expectations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations)?

Comment: "but I simulate the "work done" with the usleep" Don't. That's _synchronous_. Use proper asynchronous methods to simulate doing something asynchronously. Then use asynchronous testing (wait and expect). I don't quite see what the difficulty is. Also I agree with Paulw; if the question is _why_ does this take so long, that is the job of Instruments, not testing.